# How to compare custom class type

Tags: vb.net, object, gettype

Basically i want to compare Custom Class type

```
    Public Sub Add(items As SchoolTypes())

    Select Case items
        Case items.GetType() Is GetType(Programme)

        Case items.GetType() Is GetType(Etudiant)

        Case Else

    End Select
End Sub
```

this throw the error: 'Operator = is not defined'
I don't know how to fix that....

EDIT: when i lock a single element

```
    Public Sub Add(items As SchoolTypes())

    Select Case items
        Case items(0).GetType() Is GetType(Programme)

        Case items(0).GetType() Is GetType(Etudiant)

        Case Else

    End Select
End Sub
```

Still get the Same error..

Comment: That's an `SchoolTypes`-array so not a single object, maybe that wasn't intended, then remove the `()`.

Comment: it was intended, i just need to add an indice to my items ? sorry im new to objetcs

Comment: your `select` statement makes no sense : 
`select Case items.GetType`
`Case GetType(Programme) ...`

Comment: Im an idiot thanks Romulus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im an Idiot, my select statement makes no sense

here's the awnser:

```
        Select Case items.GetType()
        Case GetType(Programme)

        Case GetType(Etudiant)

        Case Else

    End Select
```